# How to check for a value that is inside a String array using ArrayContains method in cosmos db?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have the following JSON and I want to get this record when name="style" and properties contain US - Rectangle

```
{
    "id": "5ede1c0f1b4b335ed3bf3bca",
    "attributes": [
        {
            "name": "Style",
            "properties": [
                "US - Rectangle",
                "US - Square"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Button Configuration",
            "properties": [
                "2 button"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Columns",
            "properties": [
                "Single Column"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Colors",
            "properties": [
                "Beige"
            ]
        }
    ],

}
```

I have written this query

```sql
SELECT *
FROM c
where ARRAY_CONTAINS(c.attributes, {name:"Style"},true )
```

but not able to understand how to include the properties value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is where self-joins come into play:

Self-join on the array of attributes, then filter by doing `ARRAY_CONTAINS()` on the properties. Here is an example that emits the document id, along with the particular attribute name that contains the property `"US - Rectangle"`:

```sql
SELECT c.id,a.name FROM c
JOIN a IN c.attributes
WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(a.properties,"US - Rectangle")
```

Output:

```
[
    {
        "id": "5ede1c0f1b4b335ed3bf3bca",
        "name": "Style"
    }
]
```

If you want to limit your search to only look at one particular attribute, just add that to your WHERE clauses:

```sql
SELECT c.id, a.name FROM c
JOIN a IN c.attributes
WHERE a.name = "Style"
AND ARRAY_CONTAINS(a.properties,"US - Rectangle")
```

Comment: But what if US - Rectangle is also present in Columns, I want to check it with style.

Comment: Not sure I understand, but... in that case, the query I presented would result in two items, both with the same `id`, but each with a different `name` (one being `"Style"`, and one being `"Columns"`). In any case, the query does what you asked.

Comment: Oh - you mean you want to filter to just search one particular attribute? I edited my answer to show how to filter further.

Comment: This is working SELECT c.name FROM c
join a in c.attributes
where  array_contains(a.properties,"US - Rectangle1") and a.name="Style"

Comment: Thanks for the help, so I have to use a combination of join and array contains.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use dot accessor, like below:

```
select * from c where attributes[0].name="Style" and
attributes[0].properties="US - Rectangle"
```

Comment: But I don't know in other documents style will be on index 0 or 2 .